# How to get listname using its guid powershell CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

How to get list name using its guid in CSOM powershell

I tried:

```
$listname=$web.Lists.GetById("guid")
```

But this is not working. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert string to guide before passing it getlistbyid

```
$guid = [GUID] ("guidnumber")
$listname=$web.Lists.GetById($guid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure there are not special chars in GUID.

An example for you:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

$siteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xx"  
$userId = "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"  
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString  
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userId, $pwd)  
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)  
$ctx.credentials = $creds  
try{  
    $lists = $ctx.web.Lists  
    #$list = $lists.GetByTitle("list666")  
    $guid = [GUID] ("8A3AE548-0F20-4705-A047-5CF855543704")
    $list = $lists.GetById($guid)

    $ctx.load($list) 
    $ctx.executeQuery()  
    $list.Title

}  
catch{  
    write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code works in Powershell:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://your.sharepoint.url/any-site/"

# If the GUID is a string, set a GUID Powershell object:
$spListGUID = [GUID]"{ABCD1234-AB12-AB12-AB12-ABCDEF123456}"

#Get the list via its GUID:
$spList = $spWeb.Lists[$spListGUID]

Write-Host "List Title: " $spList.Title
```